# R geom_area tooltip always displays the same value

Tags: r, ggplot2, plotly, ggplotly, geom-area

Using the following reprex, when hovering over the upper or lower line, the tooltip keeps showing the same values. Why is that and is there any workaround?

```
library(ggplot2)
library(plotly)

df <- data.frame(a = c(2020,2021,2022,2020,2021,2022),
                 b = c('Product A','Product A','Product A','Product B','Product B','Product B'),
                 c = c(500,540,630,70,140,100))

plot <- ggplot(df, aes(x = a, y = c, fill = b)) +
  geom_area(position = 'stack')
  # geom_bar(stat = 'identity', position = 'stack')
ggplotly(plot)
```

If you comment out the geom_area row and include the geom_bar row, you will notice the problem disappears.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is due to a change in `ggplot2` (introduced sometime in the last year or so) which for a `geom_area` now uses `stat="align"` and does some interpolation. From the docs (`?geom_area`)

> To facilitate stacking, the default stat = "align" interpolates groups to a common set of x-coordinates. To turn off this interpolation, stat = "identity" can be used instead.

Apprarently this change is not supported by plotly (and I'm wondering whether this feature can be supported at all). As a result the `text` attribute will default to the value of the first data point (figured that out by inspecting the `plotly_json()` object and when trying to manually add the tooltip text).

But as the docs suggest you can fix that by switching to `stat="identity"`:

```
library(plotly, warn = FALSE)

plot <- ggplot(df, aes(x = a, y = c, fill = b)) +
  geom_area(stat = "identity")

ggplotly(plot)
```

[image]